# How can I use Processing functions in other Scala classes?

Tags: java, scala, nullpointerexception, processing

So I'm trying to make a Scala application using [Processing](https://processing.org/), and my problem relates to how I can use some of the Processing functions in other than the "main" class where the whole app is instantiated.

This is the **main Class** where the app is started.

```
import processing.core.{ PApplet, PConstants }
import attackers._

class main extends PApplet {

  override def setup() = {
    background(255, 255, 50)
  }

  override def settings() = {
    ...
  }

  override def draw() = {
    var start = new Cell(0, wHeight / 2)
    val base = new BasicAttacker(start)
    ...
    base.move()
    base.display();
  }
}

object main extends App {

  PApplet.main("tower.main")

}
```

And this is where I want to use the **fill** and **rect** functions from Processing:

```
import tower._
import processing.core.PApplet

class Base(cell: Cell) extends Basic(cell) {
  ...

  var x = cell.x
  var y = cell.y

  ...

  def display() {
    fill(150, 100, 150)
    rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  }

}
```

The error that appears is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PApplet.fill(PApplet.java:14781)
    at attackers.BasicAttacker.display(BasicAttacker.scala:27)
    at tower.Game.draw(Game.scala:73)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2482)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1547)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:313)
```

The `display()` function works when I add it to the `draw()` method in the `main`class, but somehow it fails with a **NullPointerException** when I move it to the class itself.

Any ideas on how I can use the Processing functions in other classes than the app class?

Comment: I believe there is a `dropNullValuesRecursively` but it is new. In the latest **0.13.0** release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to find an answer to this.

The problem is basically that you need to pass the "Processing sketch" as an argument in the class. For example like this:

```
 class BasicTower(c: Cell, sketch: PApplet) extends Tower(c, sketch) {

  def display() {
    sketch.fill(102, 255, 102)
    sketch.rect(cell.x, cell.y, 50, 50)
  }
 }
```

Then if you want to use it in the main processing file, it's just to write:

```
new BasicTower(Cell, this)
```

Not sure whether this is the best way to do it, but at least it works.